# best pratice for varnish cache content with authorization header

Tags: web-services, caching, authorization, varnish

I have implemented a facebook-like message system in my application, and now I try to use varnish to improve performance.(i.e. caching user message conversation). user conversation must be protected so that only authenticated user can view it.

I used oauth2 to authorize/authenticate user, so the request to retrieve user messages is something like this.

```
curl -X GET user/{id}/message/thread/{thread} -H 'Authorization: Bearer XXX'
```

As far as I understand of varnish cache, default setup of varnish will not cache the content if the request has Authorization or Cookie header, I can stripe headers info in varnish setup, but if i do so, i lost the control in backend to identify if user is authenticated user.

So my question is: what's the best practice to use varnish cache in this case?

At the moment, I have a workaround that instead send Authorization in headers, I appended it as a query string, so it will be something like

```
curl -X GET user/{id}/message/thread/{thread}?access_token=XXX
```

it works, but I felt it's not a proper way, any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Quite simply if the content changes because of a http header then you need return a Vary header specifying that.

To get Varnish to cache content with Authorization headers is easy. You just define your own `vcl_recv` method and **remove** this part:

`if (req.http.Authorization) {
    return (pass);
}`

That will let Varnish cache it. Which is the first part. The second part is to not cache content for one user and serve it to another. To do that the best way is to have your backend respond with a HTTP `Vary` header that has `Authorization` in the list. This tells Varnish that the content varies based on that header. And a change in that request header means different content.

The authorization header will be different for different users and so you will get many objects for the same url. But that's what you want.

Comment: Invoking "return (pass);" from vcl_recv will PREVENT the request from being cached. See: https://varnish-cache.org/docs/4.0/users-guide/vcl-actions.html

Comment: Bruno, yes and that's why the comment is saying to remove that part which is in the default varnish config. I've edited to make the remove word bold now

Comment: to elaborate on how to `define your own vc;_recv`: the default implementation "is executed right after any user-specified VCL, and is always present. You can not remove it. However, if you terminate the vcl_recv function using one of the terminating statements (pass, pipe, lookup, error), the default VCL will not execute, as control is handed back from the VRT (VCL Run-Time) to Varnish." https://book.varnish-software.com/3.0/VCL_Basics.html